# Enclosing Catch is not Exhaustive (Audio Recording)

Tags: swift, error-handling, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I am setting up an audio recorder but getting an error on `soundRecorder =  try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])` with the following error `Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive`

```
func setUpRecorder() {

    let recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatAppleLossless), AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue, AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2, AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ]

    var error: NSError?

    do {
        //  soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        soundRecorder =  try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        soundRecorder = nil
    }

    if let err = error {
        print("AVAudioRecorder error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        soundRecorder.delegate = self
        soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is misleading. A

```
catch let error1 as NSError
```

*is exhaustive,* because all errors are bridged to `NSError`
automatically.

It seems that the compiler is confused by the forced cast

```
recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject]
```

and that causes the wrong error message. The solution is to create the
settings dictionary with the correct type in the first place:

```
let recordSettings: [String: AnyObject] = [
    AVFormatIDKey : Int(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ]

var error: NSError?
do {
    soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)
} catch let error1 as NSError  {
    error = error1
    soundRecorder = nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There couple things that you can do.

```
do {
    //  soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject])
        soundRecorder =  try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings:     recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        soundRecorder = nil
    } catch {
      //Exhaustive catch all.
    }
}
```

Or you can just write like this

```
do {
    //  soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    soundRecorder =  try AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings as! [String : AnyObject])
} catch {
  self.error = error as NSError
  soundRecorder = nil
}
```

And that should work.